# Sorting ArrayList using Comparators, but its not showing any result

Tags: java, comparator

I'm having this problem with sorting the `ArrayList` using `Comparator`s. Below is my Main class and the class for the `Card`.

The Comparator method in the `Card` class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Card implements Comparable <Card>{ 
    // the getter and toString method are define here though.
    public static Comparator<Card> sortingHeight = new Comparator<Card>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Card s1, Card s2){
            return s2.getHeight()-s1.getHeight();
        }
    };

    public static Comparator<Card> sortingSpeed = new Comparator<Card>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Card s1, Card s2){
            return s1.getSpeed()-s2.getSpeed();
        }
    };

    public static Comparator<Card> sortingFighting = new Comparator<Card>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Card s1, Card s2){
            return s2.getFightingSkills()-s1.getFightingSkills();
        }
    };

    public static Comparator<Card> sortingTitle = new Comparator<Card>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Card s1, Card s2){
            String title1 = s1.getTitle();
            String title2 = s2.getTitle();
            return title1.compareTo(title2);
        }
    };
}
```

The Main Method:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(!false) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Title.............6" +
                            "\nHeight............7 " +
                            "\nSpeed.............8" +
                            "\nFightingSkill.....9" + 
                            "\nBack..............0"
                            );
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        int userEnter1 = scanner.nextInt();

        if (userEnter1 == 6)
            if(userEnter1 == 7)
                Collections.sort(ArrayList, Card.sortingHeight);
            else if (userEnter1 == 8)
                Collections.sort(ArrayList, Card.sortingSpeed);
            else if (userEnter1 == 9)
                Collections.sort(ArrayList, Card.sortingFighting);
            else if (userEnter1 == 0)
                increase--;
        else Collections.sort(ArrayList, Card.sortingTitle);
    }
```

It's compiling, but no result is showing when the user enters input.

Answer (score 0):

Card class does not need to implement Comparable.

the if-else statements seems weird, it should be

```
        if (userEnter1 == 6)
            Collections.sort(list, Card.sortingTitle);    
        if(userEnter1 == 7)
            Collections.sort(list, Card.sortingHeight);
        else if (userEnter1 == 8)
            Collections.sort(list, Card.sortingSpeed);
        else if (userEnter1 == 9)
            Collections.sort(list, Card.sortingFighting);
        else if (userEnter1 == 0)
            increase--;
```

And finally display the list to show the results.

```
        for (Card c: list) {
            System.out.println(c.getTitle());
        }
```